# On blackboard is it possible to open multiple scorms?

Tags: blackboard

I'm having difficulty finding way to open multiple scorms simultaneously..

Is there a setting that I need to change or blackboard does not allow multiple scorms to be opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So commonly with SCORM you have a Runtime API that is nested somewhere on the LMS web page.  This API is directly flavored for the SCO that was requested.  So having multiples trying to talk to the same API would lead to data corruption.  The only way to extend the capability for multiple shareable content objects would require more IFRAMEs.  You'd need to nest the runtime in the first IFRAME, then the Content in a sub IFRAME.  I've accomplished this with another client and it was done mainly to represent single page SCOs stacked on top of each other as a Q and A style homework display.
Is it optimal? Probably not.  Does it work? Totally. The SCORM Runtime is a JavaScript based API which is populated with a CMI object.  Namespaces within that CMI Object (get / set) from the content, however the LMS is responsible for populating its base values as well as maintaining whats allowed and not allowed.  Hope that helps, but based on your question Blackboard would have to implement that sort of module support to do it.